# Async operations with I/O Completion Ports return 0 bytes transferred

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, asynchronous, iocp

Asynchronous operations with I/O Completion Ports return 0 bytes transferred, although the I/O operations work as expected (my read buffers become full).

```
BYTE buffer[1024] = {0};
OVERLAPPED o = {0};
HANDLE file = CreateFile(
    _T("hello.txt"),
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL
);
HANDLE completion_port = CreateIoCompletionPort(
    file,
    NULL,
    0,
    0
);
ReadFile(
    file,
    buffer,
    1024,
    NULL,
    &o
);
```

In the work thread:

```
DWORD numBytes = 0;
LPOVERLAPPED po;
GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
    completion_port,
    &numBytes,
    0,
    &po,
    INFINITE
);
GetOverlappedResult(file, &o, &numBytes, FALSE);
```

Both functions return 0 bytes in numBytes, but `buffer` is filling. Is this expected behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `GetIoCompletionPort` to work correctly, you need to specify a non-null pointer to a `ULONG_PTR` for it to write the 'key' value to:

```
ULONG_PTR key;

GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
    completion_port,
    &numBytes,
    &key,
    &po,
    INFINITE
);
```

To use `GetOverlappedResult` successfully, I believe you need to specify an event handle in the `OVERLAPPED` structure (strongly recommended in any case):

```
o.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, TRUE, NULL);
```

Calling the two in succession as you were doesn't really accomplish much -- they both tell you about the same things. Though if you do call both in succession, you'll need to change the Event to be a manual-reset by changing the third parameter to `CreateEvent` to TRUE. My guess is that you were just trying both to see if you could get one to work. All things considered, I'd probably just use `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`, and leave it at that. Of course, you'll usually do more than call it once and quit. You normally call it in a loop, processing the current buffer you've read, then calling `ReadFile` again to read another buffer of info, something like this:

```
DWORD numBytes;
LPOVERLAPPED po;
while (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(completion_port, &numBytes, &key, &po, INFINITE)) {
    std::cout << "\rRead: " << numBytes; // just to show it's set correctly.
    process(buffer);
    po->offset += sizeof(buffer);
    ReadFile(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL, po);
}
```

At least in a quick test on my machine, this showed the number of bytes read correctly (`sizeof(buffer)` up to the last packet, then the remaining size of the file).

Comment: Yes, you were right about the pointer to the key. You were also right in your assumption that I tried those 2 functions to see if any of them works :-).

Thanks.